# parLapply: unused argument (MoreArgs

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

I was trying to debug a parLapply function that I am working on when I encountered an unexpected problem: the MoreArgs argument to parLapply is not working! It's 5AM at the moment, and I must be fatigued and missing something really obvious and silly, but I cannot for the life of me see what it is. Anyway, here is the minimal example that is giving me trouble:

```
require(parallel)

cluster <- makeCluster(3)
testFUN <- function(n=10, min=0, max=100, outname="test1.Rdata"){
    nums <- runif(n, min=min, max=max)
    total <- sum(nums)
    save(total, file = outname)
    return(total)

}


#just to make sure the function works
testFUN(n=5, min=4, max=150, outname = "test0.Rdata")

#make sure the cluster can get the functions
clusterExport(cluster, list("testFUN", "runif", "sum", "save"))
nlist <- list(first=5, second=10, third=15)
parLapply(cl = cluster, nlist, testFUN, outname=c("test1.Rdata", "test2.Rdata", "test3.Rdata"), MoreArgs=list(min=33, max=110))

stopCluster(cluster)
```

and the output was:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: unused argument (MoreArgs = list(min = 33, max = 110))
```

Comment: I think `MoreArgs` is used in `Map`. For `parLapply` just passing `min = 33, max = 110` directly inside `parLapply` should work. It looks like you need `clusterMap` though (over nlist and outname)

Comment: Well, that changes to a different error which is actually even more confusing to me:

`> parLapply(cl = cluster, nlist, testFUN, outname=c("test1.Rdata", "test2.Rdata", "test3.Rdata"), min=33, max=110)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid 'description' argument`

Comment: You're passing two strings to `save(..., file = outname)`.  Sleep on and look at it when you wake you with fresh eyes and a fresh mind.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is a workable example using `clusterMap()` (as already indicated by @konvas), which is easier to use in this case since there are two control variables. Also, there is no need for `clusterExport()` before the loop as long as there is no anonymous function involved that needs to access objects from the global environment.

```r
## open cluster and define function, then..

nlist = list(
  first = 5
  , second = 10
  , third = 15
)

outname = sprintf(
  "test%s.Rdata"
  , 1:3
)

clusterMap(
  cl = cluster
  , fun = testFUN
  , nlist
  , outname
  , MoreArgs = list(
    min = 33
    , max = 110
  )
)
# $first
# [1] 335.4677
# 
# $second
# [1] 681.2613
# 
# $third
# [1] 1065.619

stopCluster(
  cluster
)
```